# Non-linear system of equations involving sine

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I would like to know if it is possible to solve for $x$ and $y$ in
$$\begin{cases}
a\sin(bx+y)=c\\
dx+y=f
\end{cases}
$$
in terms of real constants $a,b,c,d,f$.

Comment: I would write $a\sin{(bx + y)} = c \Rightarrow bx + y = \arcsin{\frac{c}{a}} + n2\pi$ or $bx + y = \pi - \arcsin{\frac{c}{a}} + n2\pi$ and see if there are solutions for different values of $n$.

Comment: If $|c|\le|a|$ and $b\ne d$, yes it is.

Comment: In fact, does it make sense that $$x=\frac{\arcsin(\frac{c}{a})-f}{b-d}?$$ It seems to work but I guess there must be more solutions...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $t:=bx+y$ and rewrite the system as

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac bd(t-y)+y=f,\\\sin(t)=\dfrac ca\end{cases}.$$

Solve for $t$, then deduce $y$ and $x$.